# Possible to use Spring AOP (AspectJ) with Kotlin properties?

Tags: kotlin, spring-aop

Is it possible to use Spring AOP (AspectJ) with Kotlin properties? Specifically due to how [Kotlin compiles properties to Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#properties):

> - a getter method, with the name calculated by prepending the get    prefix
> - a setter method, with the name calculated by prepending the    set prefix (only for var properties)
> - a private field, with the same    name as the property name (only for properties with backing fields)

Consider the following minimal reproducible example:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class TestAnnotation
```

...

```
@Aspect
class TestAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(annotation)")
    fun throwingAround(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint, annotation: TestAnnotation): Any? {
        throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

...

```
internal class MinimalReproducibleExample {

    open class TestProperties {
        @TestAnnotation
        val sampleProperty: String = "sample property"

        @TestAnnotation
        fun sampleFunction(): String = "sample function"
    }

    private lateinit var testProperties: TestProperties

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        val aspectJProxyFactory = AspectJProxyFactory(TestProperties())
        aspectJProxyFactory.addAspect(TestAspect())
        val aopProxyFactory = DefaultAopProxyFactory()
        val aopProxy = aopProxyFactory.createAopProxy(aspectJProxyFactory)
        testProperties = aopProxy.proxy as TestProperties
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        println(testProperties.sampleProperty)
        println(testProperties.sampleFunction())
    }
}
```

Running the test yields:

```
null
sample function
```

When debugging I can see that the generated proxy is a cglib-backed proxy, which should be able to proxy to a concrete class, but it does not seem to invoke the configured aspect. Is there something wrong with my `@Around` definition, or is this a limitation of Kotlin properties and/or proxying concrete classes?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to trigger the aspect above with the following changes:

1. Use a "site target" for the getter: `@get:TestAnnotation`
2. Make the property/function both `open`

Comment: I do not speak Kotlin at all, but you seem to talk about [annotation use-site targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets). Quite interesting. Yes, like this an `@annotation()` pointcut would work. With Aspectj you can, however, also intercept direct field access and match field annotations directly. I just want to mention it, because Java users might also find this answer, and they do not have this Kotlin syntactic sugar at their disposal.